# Conditional Computer GPO depending on the user

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10, language-packs

I have a GPO deployement problem that I'm more and more sure it's not doable, but since I don't see how to solve it in any other way, I ask it here.

Here is my setup and what I need :

- if a user from security group grpA logs on the machine, the PC will get GPO-A
- if a user from security group grpB logs on the machine, the PC will get GPO-B

Here the single setting I'm trying to push now (windows UI language)
[GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LpLo.png)

But at the moment, whatever I do with the security filtering an/or the delegations, it only everyone gets the gpo, or noone, and when I activate both GPOs, it's the same who wins for all users whenever they are in grpA ou grpB. Who makes sense, since it's a computer setting.

But our problem is that anyone could connect on any machine, and the machine has to change language depending on who is on it, and a new user with a random language need can connect each 45 minutes (we are a school), so each machine has to be able to dynamically able to switch language.

And nothing on user settings (that I found at least), is able to change the windows UI language, the best I was able to get is that the keyboard changes as expected depending on who logs on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a Computer policy based on the logged on user is not possible, what should Windows do when two or more users connects on the same computer?

You can try to enable this policy:
[Restricts the UI languages Windows should use for the selected user](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_8.1_2012R2&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Globalization::LockUserUILanguage)
but I don't know if this will automatically switch the language for the user account.

However, maybe you can try to script the language selection with Powershell, but as far as I know you have to logoff/logon again when switching language, so this wouldn't be very user friendly...

Comment: Thanks that worked ! It might be overtaken by configs that would be in computer\policies\adm template\control panel\regional and language options, but if that is not configured the full user config works perfectly !